# How to remove already declared permissions while app update on Google Play?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, manifest, android-permissions

My app was using READ_SMS and CALL_LOG permissions. While updating  a new version the app was rejected with the following reason from Google Play:
"Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Permissions policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through the policy and make sure your app is in compliance."

In the previous version, the core functionality Default Phone handler was selected but there was no code related to it. Now I want to remove the related permissions but Google Play keeps rejecting the app with the same reason - permission compliance.

How to remove these permissions and upload a new build? Also I want to remove the the core functionalities related to the above permissions. There is no option to deselect all options in the declaration form. Where do I find these options?

Comment: where is you question brother?

Comment: nice text from google play. But you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @Avinash Ghule, If your application actually using any type of above permissions then you will have to submit permission declaration form else have to remove that from manifest those permissions. Because these are kind of dangerous permissions.

Answer (score 0):

remove read_sms and read_contacts permission from androidmanifest.xml. it violating the Permissions policy. change version code and version name. upload to play store

Comment: did you use run time permission in java file. show android manifest file

Answer (score 0):

[Please check if this is the cause of rejection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391621/google-play-services-sms-and-call-logs-permission-issue/55392826#55392826) 
Ideally, once the dangerous permissions are removed, while uploading the new apk, Playstore should not show the permission declaration form. If that form is shown, that means you still have some apk active in some channel, with the dangerous permissions. Follow the answer in the link to solve this. Basically, all the active apks in all release channels of your app should have the latest apk, without permissions.